# See unpaired bluetooth devices

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-phone

Pretty straight forward question here. I want to be able to see unpaired bluetooth devices that are near me.

My past experience with Windows Phone is that you can only see devices you have paired with in PeerFinder.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj207007(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Peerdiscovery) seems to confirm that but there is a lot of data that I'm not an expert with. I am hoping I missed something.

Is there a way to listen for Bluetooth devices from your app in C#?

Comment: Do you mean listen to see if a bluetooth device comes within range?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot yes, to see if an (unpaired) bluetooth device comes within range. I also want to do this with WIFI endpoints also.